# What does "execute a hard copy" mean?

Tags: meaning

> (ii) execute a non-electronic hard copy of this Agreement. (http://overwatchmedia.com/terms-and-conditions)

What does "execute a non-electronic hard copy" mean? Does this mean "to copy this Agreement in non-electronic way", which means to print out this Agreement? I couldn't find the meaning about this expression from any dictionaries.

Comment: That's probably what it means, but you might want to ask on on [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/), since this is legal English, not standard English.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Execute" here means:

> LAW
>
> make (a legal instrument) valid by signing or sealing it.

A "hard copy" is:

> a printed version on paper of data held in a computer

So, this is an instruction to print out a paper copy of the "Agreement" and sign it.

Comment: It's not necessarily a "domain-specific **legal**" usage. Just the contextually-relevant version of more general ***to execute** [an agreement, decision, plan]* - meaning ***to put something into practice, to make it happen***.

Comment: I just quoted directly from a dictionary. "To execute" does have a [specific legal meaning](https://thelawdictionary.org/execution/) (note all the precedents etc. cited there) in addition to its other meanings.

Comment: Yes, obviously there are genuinely domain-specific legal senses for ***execute***. But ***to execute a will***, for example, is very different from ***to sign a will***. And your legal definition would likely mislead learners who could grasp that difference without knowing anything about law.

Comment: execute here does mean to sign it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP didn't ask about executing a will. The definition I quoted in the answer is precisely the meaning invoked in the question sentence, so I'm not sure what is misleading. We both agree there are other meanings and other readers should feel free to ask about them if they are confused.

Comment: Well, I see people are upvoting your position in *comments* regarding that specific point, but I don't really understand why. I myself upvoted your *answer* because obviously what it says is actually true. But ELL isn't here to teach domain-specific usages, and I'd have thought my ***execute / sign a will*** distinction clearly illustrates the problems this can cause. If an Anglophone boss handed a customer agreement to one of his (non-native speaker) staff, with the instruction *Please execute this agreement*, he probably wouldn't be expecting the guy to just sign it and give it back!

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question _was_ about a domain-specific usage, and that's what my answer addresses. I am not sure how to improve the answer without turning it into a mere copy of a dictionary entry. If someone wants a full treatment of the possible meanings of the word, they can and should refer to a dictionary. If they have questions about what they read they can come back here and ask specific questions. I'm not an English teacher, I'm just answering a specific question on ELL.